# PHP MYSQL full join between two table using dates

Tags: php, mysql

Hiii i have two diffrent tables

1. staff_rotas (id,staff_id, startDateTime, endDateTime, rota_minutes, status)
2. staff_login (id,staff_id, actual_startDateTime,actual_endDateTime,shift_minutes, status);

I want to fetch data from both table where date between e.g (21-11-2016 to 27-11-2016) and output something like this 
[Timesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29jYA.png)

I have tried following query pls check.

```
<?php 

$staff_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff_rotas LEFT JOIN staff_login ON 
(DATE(staff_rotas.startDateTime) = DATE(staff_login.actual_startDateTime))
 WHERE staff_rotas.staff_id = '123' AND DATE_FORMAT(staff_rotas.startDateTime,'%Y-%m-%d') 
 BETWEEN '" . $date_from . "' AND '" . $date_to . "'
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM staff_rotas RIGHT JOIN staff_login ON (
 DATE(staff_login.actual_startDateTime) = DATE(staff_rotas.startDateTime)) 
 WHERE staff_login.staff_id = '123' AND 
 DATE_FORMAT(staff_login.actual_startDateTime,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '" . $date_from . "' AND '" . $date_to . "'
 ORDER BY `startDateTime` DESC")

while($data = mysql_fetch_object($staff_data)){
    /*html table to show data ......
        ...
        ...
    */
}

?>
```

Comment: Please show some sample input data along with the desired output from that sample input.

Comment: And the query where you tried to get the data

Comment: i have a query which i was trying to get data...do you need that??

Comment: Try to execute your code on DBMS (MySQL)

Comment: I have tried code shown above displaying reslut proper but taking to much time to execute bcs i have 25000 + records in both the tables is there any way I can process data in sort period of execution time....

Comment: Formatting each date might take too much time - try formatting parameters instead. Also `UNION ALL` and eliminating duplicates with `WHERE ... IS NULL` in one of the selects will speed it up, because all rows with both tables matching will be duplicated at first and then filtered.

Comment: If you write query for me it helps me a lot.